# Installation TensorFlow lite with cmake crashing

Tags: c++, cmake, tflite

I am trying to install TensorFlow Lite on my Linux machine (Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS). My aim is to use TFlite in a C++ environment for inference. It should run in combination with OpenCV using Visual Studio code IDE. C++ and OpenCV are working but until now I have troubles installing TFlite.

According to the documentation, the following steps are needed for cmake ( https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/minimal ):

1. Install cmake tool,
2. Install libffi7 package,
3. Clone the TensorFlow repo,
4. Create Cmake build directory and run Cmake tool,
5. Build TensorFlow Lite using cmake --build . -j.

This all works fine until step5 cmake --build . -j . This runs until 90% where it crashes and I cannot do anything anymore (the screen freezes).

[image]

I checked the Linux system but did not find any suspicious errors in /var/log/kern.log or /var/log/dmesg file.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-j` flag indicates how many jobs run when compiling with cmake. If unspecified, it will use as many as possible. Try changing `cmake --build . -j` to `cmake --build . -j1` which will run a single job. It will take longer but much less likely to overwhelm your computer. After that you can experiment with `cmake --build . -j<n>` where `<n>` is the number of jobs you run.